# insert a filename in db not array in CakePHP when uploading

Tags: php, database, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am using CakePHP 2.1 and trying to upload files into server.

I can successfully move the files to specified directory with manually naming a file, but its not taking the name from the
file type from view: register.

### Database table: users

```
Id Auto_Increment
username
file_name
```

### Controller : UsersController.php

```
public function register(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')){
        //   $this->data['User']['resume_file']['tmp_name'] = 'test.php';
        //  The above statement is working good

        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Message : ' . $this->data['User']['resume_file']['tmp_name']);
            //debug($this->data['User']['resume_file']['tmp_name']);

            // This is giving an error, while inserting
        }
    }
}
```

### View : users/register.php

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('file_name', array('type'=>'file', 'label'=>'Upload document') );
    echo $this->Form->end('Register');
?>
```

### Error : Database error

```
INSERT INTO `sample_db`.`users` (`file_name`, `created`) VALUES (Array, '2012-06-14 08:10:10')
```

What i seen is that, while insert into table, `Array` is inserted thats and error  `Array to string conversion` error in CakePHP
now how can i get the value of that `input type : file_name` in CakePHP

Or else if we can modify the data before saving with the below request statement..

```
$this->request->data
```

I tried to change that, with below statement

```
$this->data['User']['resume_file']['tmp_name'] = 'test.php';
```

but couldn't its returning same  error, any idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function register(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')){
        $filename = $this->request->data['User']['file_name']['tmp_name'];
        $this->data['User']['file_name'] = $filename;

        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Message : ' . $filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its still gives the same error `(`file_name`, `created`) VALUES (Array, '2012-06-14 08:10:10')`

and Notice

`Indirect modification of overloaded property UsersController::$data has no effect [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 39]`

Comment: I had edited you answer with commented statement, that is perfectly good.. but it taking the temporary value like `D:\xampp\tmp\php5500.tmp` how can i retrieve the original filename..

Comment: @Rafee: Instead of `['tmp_name']` use `['name']`. You are welcome!

Comment: okay any idea, how to get extension of file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031567/get-extension-of-uploaded-file-in-cake-php

Comment: it works for me with some changes. $this->request->data instead of $this->data