# get extension of uploaded file in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, file-extension, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and i am trying to upload files and how can i retrive the extension of the file.

### Database/users

```
Id Auto_Increment
username
file_name
```

### Controller/UsersController.php

```
public function register(){
            if ($this->request->is('post')){
                $filename = $this->data['User']['file_name']['name'];
                //$temp_ext = $this->data['User']['resume_file']['ext'];

                $this->Session->setFlash('Extension : ' . $temp_ext);
            }
}
```

When tried the above code, to get extension. it only gives single letters like L, r ie firt character of the filename but not extension

Now how can i get the extension of the file.. i gone through this link

```
http://api.cakephp.org/class/file
```

but could not understand to retrieve the file.

---

**Adding a Debug report to @Julian Hollmann**

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'file_name' => array(
            'name' => '550992_234300256686731_213914803_n.jpg',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'tmp_name' => 'D:\xampp\tmp\php866F.tmp',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 42292
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your data should be in `$this->request->data`

If you want to see what's in there, just do `debug($this->request->data);`

**Edit:**
The correct answer is:

```
$filename = $this->request->data['User']['file_name']['name'];
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

See also [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: Thanks for great help on this one.

But i need to know the extension of the file.. when i did that.. i got full details of what is the data...

and its shows the `type=>image/jpeg` and 

 `$this->data['User']['file_name']['type'])` 

 `$this->request->data['User']['file_name']['type'])`

But it showing only first letter of file name

Comment: Could you provide the full debug output of $this->request->data?

Answer (score -1):

```
$filename = $this->data['User']['file_name']['name'];
$this->request->data['User']['file_name'] = $filename;

$fileExt = explode(".", $filename);
$fileExt2 = end($fileExt);
```

Try this one... it will give you extension

Comment: Right now I will accept this answer, if `type` or `extension` values comes up from cakephp framework... do let me know..